# use caption in very single cell in a longtable

Tags: longtable

I want to caption and label every cell of  a longtable. Inside every cells is a figure inserted.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c c c}


\hskip-3.0cm
                                                    %Halogene CH3
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{CH3.jpg}
\caption{Ursprung}      
\label{Figure 2}



&\hskip-2.0cm
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{CH3_sub_F.jpg}
\caption{}
\label{Figure 3}
&\hskip-3.0cm
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{CH3_sub_Cl.jpg}
\caption{}
\label{Figure 4}
\\
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use the c-column type, but e.g.  `p{0.32\linewidth}`.

Comment: You might also want to use \captionof{figure}{...} from tje caption or capt-of packages.

Comment: Presumably this is only one row of a much larger table, so if you are committed to {ccc} then you can use \parbox of minipage for the captions.  Also, I assume your images have a lot of excess white space, as they will overlay one another with this approach.

Comment: It works with the minipage and \captionsof{figure}{...}, but after that my bibliography will not appear in the document anymore and the cite numbers can not be compiled.